# Deleting lines with different patterns in a file

Tags: bash

I need to delete lines with different patterns,

For example

```
sed '/Paris/d' file.txt |  cat -s
sed '/London/d' file.txt |  cat -s
sed '/Rome/d' file.txt |  cat -s
sed '/Pais/d' file.txt |  cat -s
```

How to do it using an array of name of cities and only type one time the command sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` in the following way:

```
sed '/paris\|london\|rome\|pais/Id' cities
```

The `I` indicates not to match the case
The `d` means delete every matching line in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

using awk:

```
awk '{if(match(tolower($0),/(paris|london|rome)/)==0) print $0}' file > file
```

`tolower` will convert entire line to lowercase
`match` returns starting position of substring if matched else 0

awk will print only the line which dosen't contain Paris,London,Rome  and save it to same file